# Passing a data attribute through a stateless component to its HTML output

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Say I have this `List` stateless component:

```
const List: React.StatelessComponent<ListProps> = props => {
    const listClasses =
        'atom-list uk-list ' +
        props.className +
        (props.striped ? ' uk-list-striped' : '')
    return (
        <ul className={listClasses}>
            {props.items.map((item, index) => {
                const itemClasses = [item.classes, props.childClasses]
                    .filter(prop => prop)
                    .join(' ')
                return (
                    <li key={index} className={itemClasses}>
                        {item.content}
                    </li>
                )
            })}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

And I use the `List` component in another stateless component, `SortableList`:

```
const SortableList: React.StatelessComponent<SortableListProps> = props => {
    const classes = 'molecule-sortableList ' + props.className
    const items = props.items.map((item, index) => {
        return { content: <div><div className="uk-sortable-handle" />{item.content}</div> }
    })
    return <List className={classes} items={items} data-uk-sortable="handle: .uk-sortable-handle" />
}
```

[Because I'm using UIKit to make the list sortable](https://getuikit.com/docs/sortable), I need to apply a data attribute to the `List` element when I use it in `SortableList`, and have that data attribute output in the resulting `ul`.

Applying the data attribute directly to the `ul` in `List` works (the attribute is output in the resulting HTML), but that's not ideal, since it requires that `List` knows something irrelevant about how it's being used.

I really want to apply the data attribute directly to `List`'s usage and have that output in the resulting `ul`. Unfortunately, doing something like this in `SortableList` doesn't seem to work:

```
return <List className={classes} items={items} data-uk-sortable="handle: .uk-sortable-handle" />
```

Why doesn't this work, and what do I need to do to pass the data attribute into `List` and have it output in the resulting `ul`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using approach similar to the following:

```
const List: React.StatelessComponent<ListProps> = (props) => {
    return (
        <div {...props}>List</div>
    );
};
```

The example is overly simplified and you should not destruct `props` directly as they contain some extra properties you do not want to be rendered as attributes. Instead you can copy all of the `props` properties that start for example with "data-" into separate object and destruct it instead.

Comment: Be warned: This answer does work, but now I'm running into problems with this causing parent `className` props to override child `className` props, so be careful where you use it.

Comment: Basically, you need to include `{...props}` before any other attributes, otherwise `props` may override them.